# Does it affect Angular performance to have everything in scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if anyone has advice for the usage of $scope vs plain JavaScript objects when inside a module. For instance I have some variables in a controller that I am attaching to $scope for my convenience but they could just be a regular object inside the controller without any functional difference.

My question is does it affect performance when Angular enters a digest cycle to have everything in scope?

Is this :

```
$scope.viewpanel = {};
$scope.viewpanel.date = new Date();
$scope.viewpanel.day = $scope.viewpanel.date.format('d');
$scope.viewpanel.week = $scope.viewpanel.date.format('W');
$scope.viewpanel.month = $scope.viewpanel.date.format('m');
$scope.viewpanel.year = $scope.viewpanel.date.format('o');
```

better or worse than this :

```
var viewpanel ={};
viewpanel.date = new Date();
viewpanel.day = viewpanel.date.format('d');
viewpanel.week = viewpanel.date.format('W');
viewpanel.month = viewpanel.date.format('m');
viewpanel.year = viewpanel.date.format('o');
```

Comment: If something else doesnt need it, like the view, probably should keep it off the scope as to not pollute it.

Comment: I can't answer the question about performance, but consider this: There is no need to pollute the scope with unneeded objects, it should be encapsulated. Consider a scenario where you have nested scopes where each scope is revealing unnecessary objects. Then it can be chaos if these objects have the same names.

Comment: Have you tried measuring?

Comment: I agree with others that out-of-scope is better style and likely better performance. As a trivial code improvement, consider not repeating "viewpanel" like so: 
`var date = new Date();
var viewpanel = {
 date: date,
 day: date.format('d'),
 week: date.format('W'),
 month: date.format('m'),
 year: date.format('o')
};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does affect performance if you are using it in your template, which creates watchers automatically. If they aren't bound to anything, then it doesn't matter that much (there is some overhead added), but lots of people don't like crowded scopes. [This wiki article on Scopes will explain exactly what happens when you add something to $scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Another alternative is bind-once or [angular-once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once). It's like regular binding but only sets it one time so it reduces the number of watchers.

Also, for your specific example, you may consider using filters to format dates. Although that won't help with performance per se, it'll give you cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I think it's time for a little refactoring ;)

Comment: Do you have a reference or two?

Comment: @mlunoe, I added a link to the wiki article explaining scopes.