# Does polluting the $scope object affect performance?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a controller where the $scope object has been used to store methods and values that are only used locally within the same controller. There is a lot of this going on:

```
$scope.foo = 'something';
$scope.bar = 'something else';
```

... and so on. None of these values are used within the view. My question is does polluting the $scope object affect performance? Is it a good idea to clean this up so only values and methods needed for the view are contained in the $scope object?

Comment: Hm, would be interesting to see an example controller. In angular the controllers are really more like view models, so usually they won't contain much that isn't used in the view. You might want to refactor some logic into services? Check out [the angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), also consider using the controllerAs syntax instead of using $scope alltogether (more on that in the guide) :)

Comment: Adding something to $scope doesn't create a watcher which is usually where performance problems come from so it won't noticeably effect performance.

Comment: This is, of course, off-topic, but why would you put values on a scope when they are not used in the View?

Comment: It is an enterprise environment where a lot of developers who didn't have much experience with Angular were working on the code. Some of the controllers are a huge mess (over 5k lines of code) and I am attempting to  clean them up. The code was written in such a tightly coupled way that cleaning it up is going to take a long time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Polluting `$scope` does affect performance, but its depends your scope has multiple watchers which are frequently changing then that will create a more overhead cost. Refer [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389218/2435473) which has covered same point

For avoiding this situation I'd suggest you to do good re-factoring of code

Handle all the logic in controller whenever required otherwise do separate a logic by making good use of each component.

1. Move common method(logic) to `service`/`factory`/`provider` which is used in multiple place, so that it would be sharable.
2. If some value are fixed, they are not gonna change then move them to `constant`/`value`
3. Whenever you feel like you have same logic which needs to be keep in `$scope` it self then move that logic to common controller. When required you could inject in your current controller scope using `$controller` injector

Also refer [**Understanding Of Scope**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for clear understanding of use of scope

Comment: Thank you for the response. The link you provided which contained the Understanding Scopes article was very helpful.