# AngularJS - what happens when you call a $scope function within a $scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization

I am writing some Angular 1.5.3 code and I am wondering about a situation where you have a $scope function calling another scope function.

E.g.

```
$scope.clickMe = function() {
    $scope.myFunction();
}

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    console.log('yadda');
}
```

What is going on internally with Angular when you do this? Is it bad practice?

Is it better to do this:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('yadda');
}

$scope.clickMe = function() {
    myFunction();
}

$scope.myOtherFunction= function() {
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: I am sure this is not encouraged. $scope.myFunction = function() {
    myFunction();
}

Comment: If you don't using `myFunction` in `scope` and its private so remove `scope` from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad practice. AngularJS does not care what function from where you call. The only "problem" might be pollution of your `$scope`.

Given that `$scope` has a prototypical inheritance like any other `Object` in JavaScript, it can become polluted rather quickly. Every time you create a nested `$scope`, it will inherit all of its parent properties and methods. For this reason it is better to keep properties/methods out of `$scope` unless you want your child components/controllers to inherit them or you need to access the from your template.

Answer (score 0):

This first snippet of your code. Attaches all the functions to the `$scope` object.

```
$scope.clickMe = function() {
    $scope.myFunction();
}

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    console.log('yadda');
}
```

So this way suppose you have nested scope. All the properties and functions on the parent scope will available to its child scope. And also you can access these properties and functions from the `view/template`.

Your second snippet on the other hand avoids having all the functions and properties to be inherited by the child scope. In this case `myFunction` will available within this scope i.e only the functions inside this scope can call/access this function. Also you can not access this function from view/template. This sort of a private function for this scope not visible

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('yadda');
}

$scope.clickMe = function() {
    myFunction();
}

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    myFunction();
}
```

Now given this its for you to decide which suits you better. Where i personally feel the second approach is better. It not a good practice to attach too much logic to scope as that will pollute the scope. You can have those functions attahed to scope which you want to be available to the child/nested scope and accessible from view/template and rest you can keep private to that scope.

[For refrence See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221978/does-polluting-the-scope-object-affect-performance)

Hope it helps :)